# smoothly animate a div to a specific location

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div move down to a specific point when a link is clicked, then back to its original point when the user goes back to the main page.

The site structure is a main page, followed by several hidden divs that are hidden/shown based on the link you click.

Basically, How can I animate a div so it smoothly moves to a specific position?

I've tried using this (I'm not exactly sure how to use .animate() as I've only used it with a background property, but I thought this would work):

```
var btns = $('#navbuttons');

btns.animate({
    bottom: 50
});
```

When I used this, I was attempting to move the element 50px from the bottom, however it didn't work. I fiddled around with the animate function for a little, however only got syntax errors (I tried using things like `-=50px` and things like that).

I had also tried using the css function inside the animate function, however, it still didn't work.

**Update:** I tried both of the answers suggestions, however I'm unable to get it to work. I pasted the related code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gYxmt/6/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the div move down by `50px`, this should work:

```
btns.animate({
    top: '+=50px'
});
```

However, you will probably need to set its position to relative first (in CSS):

```
​#navbuttons {
    position: relative;
}​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/XUdt9/

Comment: See updated question, specifically the updated part at the bottom.

Comment: You don't have jsFiddle set up correctly. You need to choose the jQuery framework from the dropdown on the left. You will also need to choose 'no wrap (head)', otherwise `onclick="serverTransition(...)"` will be undefined. And the javascript in the fiddle references elements like `#main` and `#nav` that you haven't included in the HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that, but I ended up getting this working anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close. You just need to put your value in quotes and add pixels.

```
btns.animate({
   bottom: '50px'
});
```

You will probably also need to make sure your Div [has a position specified](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp). Without being absolutely positioned, or fixed, the [bottom|top|left|right] will have no effect.

So in your CSS just make sure

```
#navButtons{
   position: absolute;
}
```

or

```
#navButtons{
   position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: @grc - It explains the same concept. If MDN had shown up higher in the Google search for "CSS Position" I would have linked to it ;)